# differing results when using model to infer on a batch vs individual with pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, training-data

I have a neural network which takes input tensor of dimension (batch_size, 100, 1, 1) and produces an output tensor of dimension (batch_size, 3, 64, 64).
I have differing results when using model to infer on a batch of two elements and on inferring on  elements individually.

With the below code I initialize a pytorch tensor of dimension (2, 100, 1, 1). I pass this tensor through the model and  I take the first element of the model output and store in variable result1. For result2  I just directly run the first element of my original input tensor through my model.

```
inputbatch=torch.randn(2, Z_DIM, 1, 1, device=device)
inputElement=inputbatch[0].unsqueeze(0)

result1=model(inputbatch)[0]
result2=model(inputElement)
```

My expectation was result1 and result2 would be same. But result1 and result2 are entirely different. Could anyone explain why the two outputs differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably because your model has some random processes that are either training specific and you have not disable them (e.g. by using `model.eval()`) or needed at the model during inference.

To test the above, use:

```py
model = model.eval()
```

before obtaining `result1`.

Comment: I thought randomness would not be an issue as for the same input I was always getting the same output which confused me.

Comment: @ArunJose_Intel Possibly due to batch norm-like layers which output different values depending on batch statistics in train mode whereas they use historical statistics in eval mode.